# _.forEach out of order

Tags: lodash

I have some code within an async function:

```
    let listOfResults = [];
    _.forEach(listOfProducts, async function (product) {
      const result = await calc.calculateProductScore(product);
      const response = await mutateDB.sendProductScoreData(result.productId, result);
      await listOfResults.push(response);
    })
    if (listOfResults.length >= 1) {
      return "yay";
    } else {
      return "boo";
    }
```

Given that there's three items in the listOfProducts array, stepping through the debugger in VS Code when this executes this happens in the following order:

1. the line `const result = await calc.calculateProductScore(product);` is executed three times
2. the if statement (which returns `boo` as nothing has been pushed onto the `listOfResults` array)
3. the line `const response = await mutateDB.sendProductScoreData(result.productId, result);` is executed three times
4. the line `await listOfResults.push(response);` is executed three times

I can see in lodash forEach documentation https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#forEach it mentions that "iteration order is not guaranteed" - should I not be using lodash then for this type of code block? How can I use Lodash and guarantee that order of code execution?

Comment: "iteration order is not guaranteed" it means the order for iterate over an Object, for an array, the order should be stable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand if I want to keep things in order I need to use a `for (const product of listOfProducts)` loop....

Answer (score 0):

Please check this good article, it's talking about the Array.forEach, but I think it should help.

https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404